# Get a link in Joomla without an alias?

Tags: php, joomla

On Joomla 1.7, Joomla allows commas in the alias. Mod_security 404s on pages with commas in the URL for security.

Gavick News Show Pro is a module for listing latest news on the homepage. The links it creates to interior pages includes aliases with the comma which we need to get stripped.

In the Gavick code it gets links this way:

`$link = ($news_id !== 0) ? JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($news_id, $news_cid)) : JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_user&view=login');`

Which produces a link such as:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=655:test,ting-here&catid=22:112th-news&Itemid=130

To note, SEF is not enabled on this site, and cannot be for security reasons. Hopefully rather than a discussion about our particular security requriments someone will be able to help resolve our issue.

Is there another method to get $link other than JRoute that will not include those aliases in the title? Example code would be great. Thank you!

Note to simplify, this code always does the same thing:

`$link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($news_id, $news_cid));`

Answer (score 0):

If SEF is not being used you don't need to pass through JRoute. The whole point of JRoute is SEF URLs.

You change the code to:

```
//Non SEF link
$ns_menuItemId = JSite::getMenu()->getActive();
$ns_link = "/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$news_id&catid=$news_cid&itemid=$nbs_menuItemId";
$link = ($news_id !== 0) ? $ns_link : JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_user&view=login');
```

Comment: Sorry doesn't work. They still pass through with your version.

Comment: Can you give me more details on how doesn't it work? I traced this through on my 1.7 dev install using this url:
`http://j16ref.site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&catid=1` and tacked it through without any alias being pulled up.

Comment: Sure what details would you like? When using your code and clicking on a link generated by the module for an article that I put in random characters in the title I get the following URL: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=657:te`~-$-^-_-{}-,-st&catid=22:112th-news&itemid=   The article and category aliases still appear.

Comment: If I put the code back to the original it produces this link: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=657:te`~-$-^-_-{}-,-st&catid=22:112th-news&Itemid=130   (And to note, the title of the test article is: "Te`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-[]\{}|;':",./?st"

Comment: So, we need to see more code, something else must be passing `$link` through JRoute to change the link from the direct one created by my code.

Comment: The value of link is used to show on the front end on the very next line after the code above, so the value of link is not changing.